# Complete an HTTP request while app closing

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, application-lifecycle

Currently I am working on a some kind of analytics sdk and we measure session lengths. But in WP when i send an http request inside PhoneApplicationService.Closing event handler, it is never completed even i await the asynchronuous operation.

I checked the Google Analytics implementation at [https://www.codeplex.com/](https://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/) but bumped into the comment **`// there is no way to get a deferral in WP so this will not actually happen until after we return to the app`**

*So what to do to make that request complete? Or what is the perfect way to measure session lengths accurately and in realtime.*

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  How are you sending the request to Google Analytics?

Comment: I don't. The sdk here https://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/team/view via measurement protocol.

Comment: If you use the measurement protocol directly you could send it as a HTTP post from the app when its closing. I have never seen that SDK before.

Comment: Assuming there is no way to do networking communication while the app is closing: You could save the session length in the Closing event handler to the isolated storage and send it to your backend once your app is started again.

Comment: then we say it is not possible to do it in realtime, right? We cannot know when would the user open the app next time and we would report the session timeout duration as the session length of the user.

Comment: I would contact the guy that created the SDK, third party SDKs always have there limitations.

Comment: sent the question to him on twitter =)